# Can't see icons within file explorer - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

I have recently discovered that when I open my File Explorer to view the Pictures folder, there are no icons or file thumbnails present.

I found that I can get them to reappear by going to View and changing the 'Layout' from Large icons to another option and then back again. However, if I progress further into a different folder, all of the icons are gone once again.

[image]

The problem also occurs when I am trying to open files in programs such as Photoshop when going to File > Open.

[image]

I have Google'd the issue and seen a few posts such as:

- [This one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/windows-10-not-able-to-view-or-preview-pictures-in/3da6bfb4-82e3-4ee5-9056-6e21a9e869d8) describing the process of setting 'Display file icon on thumbnails'
- [This one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93) describing the System File Check scan and repair
- [This one](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10) describing the process of clearing the thumbnail caché

However, none of these have solved the issue :-(

**Update:**

- I have 204GB free of 463GB on my C: drive

Comment: I think you don't have enough memory in `C:/`. Can you provide the space in that drive

Comment: @BlackThunder: 204GB free of 463GB

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc - It was difficult getting my XPS15 into safe most, but I managed it. It looks like the behaviour **DOES** occur in safe mode also

Answer (score 3):

Your thumbnails cache may be broken. You can clear it by using disk cleanup and checking "Thumbnails".
If that doesn't work you can try the following CMD commands: 
`taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` (to kill file explorer)
`del /f /s /q /a %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_*.db` (to delete the cache files) 
`start explorer.exe` (to start file explorer again)
Source of CMD commands: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10 :

> How to recreate the thumbnail cache using Command Prompt 
>   In the case, the previous steps didn't work, or you prefer to use command lines, you can use Command Prompt to delete and clear the thumbnail cache on Windows 10.
>
> Open Start.
>   Search for Command Prompt.
>   Right-click the result and select Run as administrator.
>   Type the following command to stop File Explorer and press Enter:
>
> taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
>
> Type the following command to delete all the thumbnail database files without asking for confirmation and press Enter:
>
> del /f /s /q /a %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_*.db
>
> Type the following command to start File Explorer and press Enter:
>
> start explorer.exe
>
> Close Command Prompt to complete the task

Comment: Please properly quote the relevant information from your link.  It's unclear what portion of your answer are your words, and what portion, came from the link. Proper citation is required.

Comment: I knew that this problem can occur if the thumbnails cache is broken but I wasn't sure how to probably reset it so I checked google and found the linked article. I changed it to "Source of CMD commands" I hope that's proper citation? Are there any guidelines for proper citation?

Comment: None of the information is quoted.

Comment: Hi @User025 - This is one of the first things I actually tried when I started Googling the issue, but it hasn't helped :-(

Comment: I didn't know there are lots of thumbnail caches in Windows ... my folder icons were not showing, I removed all those caches and now they're showing again

Answer (score 0):

Try another method whose idea is roughly same as your first post.

Go to the local Group Policy Editor, **User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->File Explorer**.

Click File Explorer to see the state of "Turn off the display of thumbnails and only display icons". If it is enabled, disable it.

Comment: Hmm I'm not so sure how to get to the user configs? I've Google'd but can't seem to get there.

Comment: Use the Windows+R key combination and type "gpedit.msc" in the pop-up dialog to enter the local Group Policy Editor. Then you can see "User Configuration".

Comment: Hmm. I am getting error message `Windows cannot find 'gpedit.msc'` :-/

Comment: I managed to download a setup file from here: https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/ to install stuff for the gpedit.msc. I couldn't copy files to `System32` for some reason, but I did manage to get `gpedit.msc` open, however I couldn't find the option for `File Explorer` as you instructed. I did find a tab for `Windows Explorer` however there wasn't an option for turning off thumbnails. There was however an option for turning off caching...